# Incorrect data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse site with information about film sessions. For that I'm using parser BeautifulSoup but it returns incorrect data. For example, if I manually check it directly in code [page](https://planetakino.ua/lvov2/movies/deadpool_2/#cinetech_2d_3d_4dx_week), it has times at 27th: 23:45, 19:40. But it returns incorrect list `['21:00', '23:00']` and incorrect data from div:

```
<div class="showtimes-line has-21 has-23">
 <div class="showtimes-line-technology t-cinetech t-2d">
  <div class="showtimes-line-technology-title ">
   Cinetech+, 2D
  </div>
  <div class="showtimes-line-hours-wrapper">
   <a class="time h-21 " data-brand="Планета Кіно" data-category="2d" data-id="00000000000000000000000000000631" data-list="movie" data-name="Дедпул 2 (18+)" data-position="4" data-seat="" href="https://pay.planetakino.ua/hall/imax-kiev/484437" rel="nofollow">
    21:00
   </a>
   <a class="time h-23 " data-brand="Планета Кіно" data-category="2d" data-id="00000000000000000000000000000631" data-list="movie" data-name="Дедпул 2 (18+)" data-position="5" data-seat="" href="https://pay.planetakino.ua/hall/imax-kiev/486327" rel="nofollow">
    23:00
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
def get_sessions(response, date):
    """Return information about sessions at `date`."""
    sessions = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    days_div = soup.find_all('div', class_='showtimes-row')

    for div in days_div:
        day_str = div.find('span', class_='date').text
        day_int = int(day_str.split()[0])

        if int(date.day) == day_int:
            sessions_row = div.find('div', class_='showtimes-line')
            for session in sessions_row.find_all('a', class_='time'):
                sessions.append(session.text.strip())
            print(sessions) 
            print(sessions_row.prettify())

    return sessions
```

The request was made as follows:

```
url='https://planetakino.ua/lvov2/movies/deadpool_2/#cinetech_2d_3d_4dx_week'
response = requests.get(url)
sessions = get_sessions(response, film.period)
```

Comment: could you possibly provide the requests that you are sending?

Comment: @Fozoro yes, question was updated

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I have two more questions for you, Do you just want the sessions of a given website? and what does `film.period` represent?

Comment: @Fozoro I want a list of sessions at date which is specified at film.period (object of datetime). I compare days of dates here `if int(date.day) == day_int`.

Comment: the code you gave is correct. the wrong data you see does not come from this page.

Comment: @bobrobbob, Ok, i tested this [code](https://gist.github.com/PetrushynskyiOleksii/7d6c0ce4e7b4c88a8dbd2aee0c683378). It returned list `['21:00', '23:00']` again. Maybe i do a bad request, idc.

Comment: @bobrobbob what? there is output of my console in PyCharm: `/home/fnt/.pyenv/versions/bot_env/bin/python /media/fnt/37443b2c-aafa-4e23-bf42-473bfb4d48e6/fantbook/projects/telegram_bot/main/test.py
['21:00', '23:00']

Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: @bobrobbob , @Fozoro I found where can be a problem, when i do request, it return me a page from another cinema (in Kiev). I think it happens, because of redirects (i wrote cinema directly in URL `/lvov2/`). But if i do with requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False), the response is empty. Can u give me some advice, how i can fix this?

Comment: if i do with `requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)` nothing changes: the result is still `['23:45', '19:40']` and yes you're in another page. which is impossible if you used the code you posted. so the problem may be that `FilmSession()` doesn't just give you a date but also a wrong url. but you insist in not showing that code...

Comment: @bobrobbob he provided the code in one of the previous comments and it gives the correct output `['23:45', '19:40']`.

Comment: @Jatimir that's why i called him a troll. this is not the code he's really using

Comment: @OleksiiPetrushynskyi your code seems to do what you want, to check for redirects, post the output of `response.history` or `response.is_redirect`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't noticed that you provided `film.period` in the code hosted on Github, so I didn't bother to debug your code without that and decided to implement it from scratch.

After a quick search, I found out that the Planeta Kino cinema has XML files on their website with the showtimes of the movies. You can find some of them [here](http://planetakino.ua/lvov2/i/showtimes/). I'm not sure why, but there was no entry for `lvov2` cinema with the showtimes corresponding to the link from your question. However, I managed to find it, by simply changing part of the URL: http://planetakino.ua/lvov2/ua/showtimes/xml/.

The code below should do exactly what you want:

```
import datetime
from typing import List

import dateparser
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

Date = datetime.datetime
Screening = Tag
Screenings = List[Tag]


def get_movie_id(soup: BeautifulSoup, searched_movie: str) -> int:
    movie = soup.find(
        lambda elem: elem.name == 'movie' and searched_movie in elem.title.string
    )
    movie_id = int(movie['id'])
    return movie_id


def get_movie_screenings(soup: BeautifulSoup, movie_id: int, searched_date: Date) -> Screenings:
    formatted_date = searched_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    screenings = soup.select(f'showtimes '
                             f'> day[date={formatted_date}] '
                             f'> show[movie-id={movie_id}]')
    return screenings


def get_show_times(searched_movie: str, searched_date: Date) -> Screenings:
    url = 'http://planetakino.ua/lvov2/ua/showtimes/xml/'
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')

    movie_id = get_movie_id(soup, searched_movie)
    screenings = get_movie_screenings(soup, movie_id, searched_date)
    return screenings


date = dateparser.parse(input('Type the date: '))
if date is not None:
    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(get_show_times('Дедпул 2', date))
else:
    print('Sorry, I cannot parse the date you gave me.')
```

**Output:**

```
Type the date: 27 червня, середа
[<show full-date="2018-06-27 19:40:00" hall-id="104" movie-id="2385" order-url="https://pay.planetakino.ua/hall/pk-lvov2/485693" technology="Cinetech+2D" theatre-id="pk-lvov2" time="19:40"/>,
 <show full-date="2018-06-27 23:45:00" hall-id="101" movie-id="2385" order-url="https://pay.planetakino.ua/hall/pk-lvov2/485506" technology="4dx" theatre-id="pk-lvov2" time="23:45"/>]
```

I used [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.1/) to parse the input date, so it works with different formats, languages, e.g. `27th June`, `27 червня, середа` and a lot more. It's really great and I love it.

Take your time to read and understand the code, you might wanna look at [`.select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) ([child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) and [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)).

*Note: You need to use Python 3.6+, since I used [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (`f-strings`) and type hinting (3.5+).*

Comment: his code already does exactly what he wants: wasting *your* time